# Как сохранить сообщение пользователя в кнопку и чтобы он мог вывести это сообщение telegrambot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как можно реализовать подобную функцию на языке python желательно с помощью библиотеке telebot [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мы пишем текст и бот должен его сохранить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И когда мы нажимаем на пункт список задач, текст пользователя должен сохраниться в эту кнопку и пользователем мог всячески манипулировать ей

Answer (score 0):

Желательно выкладывать код, что бы другие пользователи могли понимать в чём конкретно проблема.

Я бы сделал так. Список задач имеет (список/словарь/кортеж, кому как удобнее). в него записываются через глобальную функцию данные, которые потом можно вытаскивать.